# Check if a class doesn't exist on a page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check if the div `.full-screen` doesn't exist on a page, is this the right way to do it?

```
if (!$(".full-screen").length) {

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 50) { // this refers to window
            $(".header-container").addClass('transparent-menu');
        } else {
            $(".header-container").removeClass('transparent-menu');  
        }
    }); 

}
```

The inner function runs regardless even though I know the class doesn't exist on the page.

Comment: That code should work fine

Comment: Yes, is it _**a**_ right way to do it.

Comment: This code looks fine, please check if you have this class enabled or not.

Comment: This might be happening because the class existed initially and the window scroll logic got bound at that time. You also have to unbind it when the class is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want your inner function run when class **Not Found** in your code , you must use

```
if (!$(".full-screen").length){inner functions}
```

if you want your inner function run when class **Found** in your code , you must use

```
if ($(".full-screen").length){inner functions}
```

Comment: Although that's the same as my original code, it worked. I must've had something else clashing. I can't delete the question so I'll just accept this as it's correct

Answer (score 0):

Considering a scenario that the class existed and your logic got bound with window scroll event, but when the class is missing, it also needs to unbind, so try like:

```
if (!$(".full-screen").length) {
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 50) { // this refers to window
        $(".header-container").addClass('transparent-menu');
    } else {
        $(".header-container").removeClass('transparent-menu');  
    }
  }); 

} else {
    $(window).off("scroll");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with hasClass() method over the Document:

```
if (!$(document).hasClass(".full-screen")) {

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 50) { // this refers to window
            $(".header-container").addClass('transparent-menu');
        } else {
            $(".header-container").removeClass('transparent-menu');  
        }
    }); 

}
```

Comment: `hasClass(".full-screen")` will check if the element has the class `.full-screen` and not if it has the class `full-screen`. Beside that this would not do what the OP is asking.